# How to set System Properties on run time Spring 3 MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, ssl

Currently we have the bean definition below to set javax.net.ssl.trustStore

```
<bean id="trustStore" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetObject" value="#{@systemProperties}" />
    <property name="targetMethod" value="putAll" />
    <property name="arguments">
        <props>
            <prop key="javax.net.ssl.trustStore">../path_to/cacerts</prop>
            <prop key="javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword">changeit</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Is it possible to set javax.net.ssl.trustStore on runtime?
I understand there is something like:

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "D:/cacerts");
```

`System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "changeit");`

The problem I got with this implementation though is that when a change is made to the 'cacerts' file, such change won't reflect unless a restart to the application is done. I would like to know if there is a way to do this dynamically.

We have a feature which changes the 'cacerts'.

I have tried looking into this link but I'm having a hard time understanding the logic.

http://java.dzone.com/articles/dynamic-property-management

PS: I'm still new in spring.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Create custom `FactoryBean` for properties:

```
public class SysConfigPropertiesFactoryBean implements FactoryBean<Properties> {

    public final boolean isSingleton() {
        return true;
    }

    public Class<Properties> getObjectType() {
        return Properties.class;
    }

    public final Properties getObject() {
        // filtering or any other operation here
        return System.getProperties();
    }

}
```

Define a properties bean:

```
<bean id="sysConfig" class="xxx.SysConfigPropertiesFactoryBean"/>
```

You can use it:

**in xml:**

```
<bean class="...">
   <property name="targetObject" value="#{sysConfig.property}" />
</bean>
```

**using single value:**

```
 @Value("#{sysConfig.propertyName}")
 private String propertyValue;
```

**as `@Autowire`** for complete Properties object:

```
 @Autowired
 @Qualifier("sysConfig")
 private java.util.Properties systemProperties;
```

Comment: Hi jw23.
Thanks for the reply.
I was wondering, how will I be able to use this one on my code?
Say for example, on my @Controller class?

Will I be able to directly say ??:
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore","../new_path/cacerts");

Or do you mean that by having this, once a System.setProperty is called, such property value is really changed during runtime?

Please expound.

Cheers! :)

Comment: **No** ,they are evaluated on startup.

Comment: Does this mean that it's not possible to have this changed on run time?
I have this working on startup. I need to do this as well on runtime.
Thanks

Comment: It is possible by reading the value from `system properties` each time you want to use it.

Comment: Hi jw23.
Could you post a link or code snippet for such implementation?
I would be very grateful if you could.
Cheers! :)

Comment: @Miki: I added it to my answer, use the version with \@Autowire and simply read the value each time you need it.